Group by 2 keys in structured object in javascript
I have a javascript array called weeklySchedule which comes back from an API call. A shortened example of my data is:
[
{
        "PlayerNumber": 1,
        "TeeOff": 1,
        "WeekNumber": 1,
        "PlayerName": {
            "FirstName": "Bob",
            "LastName": "Jones"
        }
    }, {
        "PlayerNumber": 2,
        "TeeOff": 1,
        "WeekNumber": 1,
        "PlayerName": {
            "FirstName": "Dave",
            "LastName": "Wilson"
        }
    }, {
        "PlayerNumber": 3,
        "TeeOff": 2,
        "WeekNumber": 1,
        "PlayerName": {
            "FirstName": "Homer",
            "LastName": "Simpson"
        }
    }, {
        "PlayerNumber": 4,
        "TeeOff": 2,
        "WeekNumber": 1,
        "PlayerName": {
            "FirstName": "Lisa",
            "LastName": "Simpson"
        }
    }
]

...this data continues with multiple weeks and multiple TeeOff values
I would like to group these by WeekNumber and TeeOff, and then sort them by those two keys, first by WeekNumber then by TeeOff. I have the group by working:
const groupedPlayers=Object.groupBy(weeklySchedule,
    function (item) {
        const group = [item.WeekNumber, item.TeeOff];
        return group;
    });

However, when I iterate through these, the order is indeterminate, even though the data is presorted, for example:
for (const key in groupedPlayers) {
 //the key is not in any expected order
}

I have searched high and low, read dozens of examples, but nothing I've seen will group and order by 2 separate properties. Can you please help!?!

what is your expected output, please provide

I'm flexible on my output. The output of "groupedPlayers" is satisfactory provided I can iterate through the array in the order as described.

There appears to be a WeekNumber  field and WeekNumber field in some of the sample entries from the API. Is this only a  typo in the question or an error in the API response?

Object.groupBy takes a callback and expects it to return a key by which objects will be grouped. You return an array, which is cast into a comma-separated string and happens to be used as a key, but that's not really how it's meant to be used.

Does this answer your question? Grouping by multiple fields per object

I wonder if a plain 'ol arr.sort((a, b) => a["WeekNumber"] - b["WeekNumber"]) would organize things the way you're hoping.

@OluwafemiSule sorry, just a typo in the translation to the post. I fixed the extra space. The data is correct.

You can group players in 2 nested objects. Since your sort values are numbers they will be sorted automatically! Then you can transform the grouped data to any format you want. For example I've transformed into arrays of week numbers and nested array of tee offs, since I find using arrays the most helpful (you can use array methods on data):


const arr = [
{
        "PlayerNumber": 1,
        "TeeOff": 1,
        "WeekNumber": 1,
        "PlayerName": {
            "FirstName": "Bob",
            "LastName": "Jones"
        }
    }, {
        "PlayerNumber": 2,
        "TeeOff": 1,
        "WeekNumber": 2,
        "PlayerName": {
            "FirstName": "Dave",
            "LastName": "Wilson"
        }
    }, {
        "PlayerNumber": 3,
        "TeeOff": 2,
        "WeekNumber": 1,
        "PlayerName": {
            "FirstName": "Homer",
            "LastName": "Simpson"
        }
    }, {
        "PlayerNumber": 4,
        "TeeOff": 2,
        "WeekNumber": 2,
        "PlayerName": {
            "FirstName": "Lisa",
            "LastName": "Simpson"
        }
    }
]

const grouped = arr.reduce((r, item) => (((r[item.WeekNumber] ??= {})[item.TeeOff] ??= []).push(item), r), {});
console.log(grouped);
const result = Object.entries(grouped).map(([WeekNumber, teeOffs]) => 
({WeekNumber, TeeOffs: Object.entries(teeOffs).map(([TeeOff, Players]) => ({TeeOff, Players}))}));

console.log(result);
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}



